# scrartcl @a1paper with 20pt

Tags: fonts, fontsize, document-classes, class-options

want to mirrow a power-point-poster to tex by an own class. First my plan is, to write a working preamble and convert it to a class.

My first step: Chose the right font-size. For Din-A1 20pt seems to be good. (Is there any iso for this?)

This font-size should depend on the chosen "aXpaper". So my class will take to option a0-a5 and make the setup automatically.

Since I get warnings by using

```
\documentclass[a1paper, twocolumn, 20pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
```

I'm here to ask. My warning is "you've used obsolete option '20pt'".

The "defining a class"-behaviour will be ask seperate. I need a solution for:

- which font-size for which Din-AX?
- why do I get those warnings and how to cancel that?

Thank you

Comment: If I try a `scrartcl` with the option 20pt, the warning ends with "you should simply replace option 20pt by fontsize=20pt".

Comment: There already are a few packages and classes for posters available. Have you seen them?

Comment: I just saw "a0poster" and "sciposter". Right now I found "beamerposter" and I guess, that this class would be the one, I have to choose. @IanThompson thank you, my Texniccenter2 doesn't told me that.

Comment: @Shalec --- If your editor hides the messages produced by the engine, then change your settings, or change your editor!